# STG_E_FILEALREADY Exists 0x80030050 ssrs while preview the report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

i'm pdating a ssrs report
The Query is working properly
But while preview  it is throwing this error

An error has occurred in the local report process already exists 0x80030050 (STG_E_FILEALREADYExists )

How to fix this error
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Delete the `<report name>.rdl.data` file and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today--I was able to fix it by excluding the problem report from my solution and then importing it back in again. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a backup copy of both report definition and `.edl.data` data file.
2. Delete the report from solutions explorer in Visual Studio. This will also delete the files on your system
3. Solutions explorer -> rt.click report -> add -> existing item. Select this back up files.